# 多次元配列内での$_SESSIONの使用方法

Tags: php, session

あるショッピングカートのphpファイルで下記の様に、var_dump($_SESSION);を試すと、その右側の結果が表示されます。
その表示された中のproduct_idである1322を$_SESSIONで取得するにはどのような設定にすべきかご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

var_dump($_SESSION);　-> array(11) { ["cart"]=> array(1) { [1]=> array(3) { [1]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(4) "1260" ["quantity"]=> int(4) ["cart_no"]=> int(1) ["productsClass"]=> array(15) { ["product_id"]=> string(4) "1322" ["stock"]=> NULL ["stock_unlimited"]=> string(1) "1" ["sale_limit"]=> string(2) "88" ["price02"]=> string(1) "1" ["point_rate"]=> string(1) "5" ["product_code"]=> string(2) "99" ["product_class_id"]=> string(4) "1260" ["classcategory_name1"]=> NULL ["class_name1"]=> NULL ["classcategory_name2"]=> NULL ["class_name2"]=> NULL ["main_image"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(2) "kk" ["main_list_image"]=> string(26)"09241340_5ba86ada23ca6.jpg" } ["price"]=> string(1) "1" ["point_rate"]=> string(1) "5" ["total_inctax"]=> float(4) } ["cancel_purchase"]=> bool(false) [0]=> array(4) { ["price"]=> string(0) "" ["quantity"]=> string(0) "" ["point_rate"]=> string(0) "" ["id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } } } } ..........

以下はいろいろと試した結果です。

var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);   -> 上記の["cart"]=>以降が表示されます。
var_dump($_SESSION['product_id']);　　->　NULL
var_dump($_SESSION['cart']['product_id']);　　->　NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ご質問への回答

該当の `var_dump()` のログを観察すると、
大まかに
`["キー名"]=> 型の名前 中身の値`
という並びになっています。このルールで、試しに手で内容を解釈すると、
以下のようにインデントを掛けることができました。

```
array(11) {
    ["cart"]=> array(1) {
        [1]=> array(3) {
            [1]=> array(7) {
                ["id"]=> string(4) "1260"
                ["quantity"]=> int(4)
                ["cart_no"]=> int(1)
                ["productsClass"]=> array(15) {
                    ["product_id"]=> string(4)"1322"
                    ["stock"]=> NULL
                    ["stock_unlimited"]=> string(1) "1"
                    ["sale_limit"]=> string(2) "88"
                    ["price02"]=> string(1) "1"
                    ["point_rate"]=> string(1) "5"
                    ["product_code"]=> string(2) "99"
                    ["product_class_id"]=> string(4) "1260"
                    ["classcategory_name1"]=> NULL
                    ["class_name1"]=> NULL
                    ["classcategory_name2"]=> NULL
                    ["class_name2"]=> NULL
                    ["main_image"]=> NULL
                    ["name"]=> string(2) "kk"
                    ["main_list_image"]=> string(26)"09241340_5ba86ada23ca6.jpg"
                }
                ["price"]=> string(1) "1"
                ["point_rate"]=> string(1) "5"
                ["total_inctax"]=> float(4)
            }
            ["cancel_purchase"]=> bool(false)
            [0]=> array(4) {
                ["price"]=> string(0) ""
                ["quantity"]=> string(0) ""
                ["point_rate"]=> string(0) ""
                ["id"]=> array(1) {
                    [0]=> string(0) ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
    :
```

ここから読み取れるのは、

1. `$_SESSION` は11個の要素を持つ配列である
2. ツリー構造になっている
3. ツリーを辿ると `$_SESSION["cart"][1][1]["productsClass"]["product_id"]` に `"1322"` が入っている

といったあたりです。
(少しcartの直下の構造が奇妙な気がしますが、このログからはこのように読み取れます)

## 気になった点

2つほど気になった点があります。

### `$_SESSION` 登録側コードとの一貫性

`$_SESSION` そのものを発行するコードをお作りになられたのも質問者さんでしょうか……？
`$_SESSION` にデータを仕掛ける側のコードを調べ、そちらと仕様を合わせたほうがいいかもしれません。

### `var_dump()` の利用

有効なPHPコードの形でデータを出力する `var_export()` や
よく知られたフォーマットである `json_encode()` 等によって変換した文字列を出すと、
`var_dump()` より、情報を読み取りやすいかもしれません。次に出力するときに試してみるとよいかも。

Comment: rugamaga様、

お時間、そして含蓄に富んだ解説を頂きましてありがとうございます。

見事に以下で1322を取得できております。かなり時間をかけても解決できませんでしたので、感謝の限りでございます。

$product_id = $_SESSION["cart"][1][1]["productsClass"]["product_id"];

この記述で、このページに関する限り、どのような状況にも対応できるのでしょうか。
あるいはこの記述では状況によってはproduct_idの数字を取得できないことがあり得るのでしょうか。$_SESSIONの仕掛けるコードを調べようと思いますが、
私はその様なコードを作成できませんので、[1]が変動するものなのかなどが分かりません。

Comment: 残念ながらこれで必ず取得出来るとは考えにくいです。 `$_SESSION` を設定する側のコードの挙動か、またはここに入るデータの仕様が必要になるでしょう。

ところで、このプログラムはどのような事情で作成しているでしょうか。一時的に作れれば十分なプログラムでしょうか……？

Comment: rugamaga様、一時的なものではなく、ecサイトの商品詳細ページからカート処理関連の流れで辿り着くページで、よって商品毎にproduct_idが変動するなかで、
product_idを取得する必要があり、$_SESSIONでの取得が正攻法かなということでの試みでした。

Comment: baseballjapanさんは、ECサイトを作成しているのですね。自分自身ではわからない範囲ということはお仕事関連で、別のメンバーも関わっているような状態でしょうか……？もしかしたら直接そのSESSION値を入れたメンバーにお話を聞いたほうが良い結果になるかもしれません。どのようなコードであるべきか、どのように作るべきか、というのはそのサイトに関わる、自分たち自身がどうありたいか、であるからです。それはメンバーと話をすることでしかわからない情報ですから。。。